# Who can come up with a better hack to log off my Windows account within Citrix Receiver?

Tags: logout, citrix-receiver

My company uses Citrix Receiver so I can access programs on our company server, basically it's remote desktop only I don't get a desktop I just get an application (or applications) that look like it's running right on my computer. It's an okay system but very buggy and doesn't seem to be designed by the brightest programmers, the programs crash and freeze frequently, that's a whole other subject though.

My issue is Citrix tends to fail at gracefully closing connections and that leaves the program (we'll call it SM, it's a buggy in-house made Microsoft Access 2013 program) open on the server, which can not run in more than one instance and I have no desktop to view to close the open program. So when I go to reconnect it tells me SM is already open and disconnects, there's no options.

So my hack of a fix is I open Microsoft Outlook 2013 in Citrix (it's another one of my Citrix accessible programs on the server), then I go to File - Open & Export - Open Calendar - next to "File name:" I change "iCalendar format" to "All Files" - then I navigate to C:\Windows\system32\ - there I right click on "taskmgr.exe" and select Open - from here I go to the Users tab, look for my user name, and select Logoff. After this lengthy process all my programs save any open info and close, letting me open Citrix again and open SM again.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this process faster? My Citrix applications are Microsoft Excel, OneNote, Outlook, PowerPoint, Publisher, and Word, all 2013, also I can get to Chrome by using my above hack. Maybe a way to make it where I can email myself a certain command that makes it log off, but I'm open to anything. Also this is not an admin account so can't install new programs very often.

Comment: What does your IT Administrator have to say?

Comment: His only fix is for us to call him and ask for him to log us off, he just goes to the server and opens Task Manager, then like me looks for our username and kicks us off. Or wait till midnight for the server to do it's daily restart. The issue is he's only in one day a week, so any other day of the week we could be out in the middle of nowhere unable to connect to see where our next job location is. And no he won't fix this issue, or doesn't know how.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found a partial fix. Per this link http://www.guidingtech.com/29533/shutdown-windows-remotely-outlook/ I set up a rule in Outlook to whenever I receive an email with the subject "LOGOFF" from myself only it will delete the email then run a simple bat file I made with "shutdown.exe -l -f" (not sure if -f is needed, will test tomorrow) as the only thing in it. Per this method it's exactly what I've been dreaming of, however for some odd reason Outlook 2013 has zero options to run in the background (this is insane to me), so I still have to use Citrix and open Outlook, but once it opens it sees the email and logs everything off. So... if anyone has any idea to keep Outlook running please suggest it. However over all I figure this is worthy as an answer, just open to improvement.